# How to 'select' the current identity value for a table?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, identity, datareader

`dbcc checkident (MyTable, NORESEED)`

Will show the identity value in a message. I can't see the message as I need to `select` the identity value through a `DataReader`.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks folks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable')
```

See [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098(v=SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: Excellent, I knew there had to be a way to do it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE_NAME')
```

returns  `NULL` if there is no identity defined in the table

Answer (score 1):

```
 select @@identity
```

might work,

there is also

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: I'm guess the downvote, because that returns the identity of the row you just inserted. I'm not inserting any rows, but need to know the current identity value of the table

Comment: This is not correct. @@identity can be for any table. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167(SQL.80).aspx. **@@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. **

Comment: You don't specify the table to get the last identity from. So you can't get the identity of any table. It's always the table where you have inserted some rows just before.